# How to extract the rows given a condition?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix from which I only want to extract the first 20000 rows where the number in the 3rd column is greater/less than a specific quantity. I tried the following but it doesn't work and stores a totally wrong matrix into **temp** variable:

```
temp <- var[var[1:20000, 3]<60, ]
```

However, the following works but extracts **all** rows where the determined condition is satisfied:

```
temp <- var[var[, 3]<60, ]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `head(var[var[,3]<60, ], 20000)` or `var[var[, 3]<60, ][1:20000, ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
temp <- var[var[, 3]<60, ][1:2000,] # Only keep the first 20000 rows of the result
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 definitely works. I was just curious how another approach might work. This one uses the R package data.table. It might be a good fit since your asking for a subset of 20,000 rows. data.table is great for sub-setting and preforming calculations on really large data sets (millions of rows). If you actually need the 20000 x n matrix for matrix operations this might be a good start for sub-setting a really large structure into smaller parts and then transforming back to a matrix type structure. At any rate sorry for the long winded introduction.

**Setup:**

```
matrixGenerator <- matrix(rnorm(4000,25,2.5),ncol=4) # sample matrix
    library(data.table)
    var <- data.table(matrixGenerator) # covert matrix to data.table 
    str(var) # what does var look like
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 1000 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ V1: num  24.5 23.3 23 30.4 21.3 ...
     $ V2: num  27.8 29.8 23.2 23.2 20.1 ...
     $ V3: num  24.8 23.2 25.3 23.2 27.9 ...
     $ V4: num  29.4 26.8 23.5 29.9 23.6 ...
# data.table names the columns so you'll have to use those in the syntax below
```

**data.table structure from an sql perspective:**
[i,j,k] = [where,select,group by]

**So to the original question:**

```
    var[V1<20,head(.SD,10),] # give rows where V1 < 20 and head() returns 10
          V1       V2       V3       V4
 1: 15.31989 19.65829 23.63891 26.03069
 2: 17.45041 29.99338 25.90798 23.26868
 3: 18.07311 27.82854 27.09712 24.78181
 4: 19.13734 28.47680 22.40267 28.63907
 5: 17.75329 22.03210 28.89607 25.69952
 6: 19.66230 24.42867 21.84213 21.53471
 7: 19.05977 28.76396 29.83406 28.11025
 8: 19.29034 29.50401 24.77912 24.30352
 9: 18.92708 24.79214 20.27407 27.51422
10: 17.77079 20.48539 27.72196 28.94075
```

At the end of the day you'd have to convert this back to a matrix if you actually need one, but for me it's fun to think of different ways to answer the same problem. I've benefited from that approach. Much more on data.table here:  [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)